# Empty Function use in Javascript

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I am trying to understand a third party Javascript code.
But am not able to figure out what is the use of the below coding style.

```
 function A(){
    }
A.Prop = '23';
A.generate = function(n){
   // do something
}
```

And then it is just used as :

```
A.generate(name);
```

Can someone explain what this code is doing.
I understand some bit of OO Javascript, but i wonder if this is any other form of extending an object with new properties to it. Though i dont see any "new" keyword being used, to create an object.

Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are creating a namespace. There are many ways to do this, and all are more-or-less equivalent:

```
A = {
    Prop : '23',
    generate : function (n) {
        // do something
    }
};
```

Or, equivalently:

```
A = { };
A.Prop = '23';
A.generate = function (n) {
    // do something
};
```

Also, if you like being verbose:

```
A = new Object();
A.Prop = '23';
A.generate = function (n) {
    // do something
};
```

`function` is usually used to denote a "class" rather than a "namespace", like so:

```
A = (function () {
    var propValue = '23';    // class local variable
    return {
        "Prop" : propValue,
        "generate" : function (n) {
            // do something
        }
    };
})();
// then I can use A in the same way as before:
A.generate(name);
```

Comment: well you should read this book for more professional patterns http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Answer (score 4):

It looks like they're using a dummy function to create a namespace.

You're right; this is useless.
They should use a normal object instead.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, i was thinking on the same lines. But do you know will there be any performance issue, using this coding style. I mean to say is this a general way to create namespaces. I would assume `code` var A = new function(){}(); `code` to do something like this, if i dont touch the whole codebase ?

Comment: The correct way to create a namespace is to use an object literal: `var a = { };`.

Comment: Unless they want to support "instances" of that object, right? function A(){} allows for the `var a = new A();` pattern, I think.

Comment: @Andrew: But they're not making a class.

Comment: @SLaks, what specifically makes you sure of that?

Comment: @Andrew: They're only using it as a namespace.

Comment: @SLaks: Isn't that assuming the conclusion?  How do you know that's being used as a namespace without more context?

Answer (score 0):

A function is an object, there's nothing inherently wrong with using it the way it's been used. However, since the function isn't actually used as a function, it would be better to use an Object. You could also use an Array (which is an object), but the same advice applies.

Also, identifiers starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors (unless they are all capitals, which are, by convention, for constants) so use a name starting with a lower-case letter.